# Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Tags: php, pdo

Como resolvo isso ?

> **Warning**: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\loja\classes\Site.class.php on
>   line 81
>
> **Warning**: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\loja\classes\Site.class.php
>   on line 83
>
> **Warning**: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\loja\classes\Site.class.php on line 89

```
class Site extends BD{

private $conexao;

public function getData(){
    $data = getdate();
    $diaHoje = date('d');
    $array_meses = array(1 => "Janeiro", 2 => "Fevereiro", 3 => "Março", 4 => "Abril", 5 => "Maio", 6 => "Junho", 
                         7 => "Julho", 8 => "Agosto", 9 => "Setembro", 10 => "Outubro", 11 => "Novembro", 12 => "Dezembro");

    $horaAgora = date('H:i');
    $mesgetdate = $data['mon'];
    $anoAtual = date('Y');

    return 'Hoje, '.$diaHoje.' de '.$array_meses[$mesgetdate].' de '.$anoAtual.', às '.$horaAgora.'';
}// Armazena e retorna a string da data atual.


public function getMenu(){
    $imagem_cat = '<img src="'.PATH.'/images/add.png" border="0"/>';
    $imagem_subcat = '<img src="'.PATH.'/images/arrow.png" border="0"/>';

    $pegar_categorias = "SELECT * FROM `loja_categorias` ORDER BY id DESC";
    $executar = self::conn()->prepare($pegar_categorias);
    $executar->execute();
    if($executar->rowCount() == 0){}else{
        while($categoria = $executar->fetchObject()){
            echo '<li>'.$imagem_cat.'<a href="'.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'">'.$categoria->titulo.'';

                $pegar_subcategorias = "SELECT * FROM `loja_subcategorias` WHERE id_cat = ?";
                $executar_sub = self::conn()->prepare($pegar_subcategorias);
                $executar_sub->execute(array($categoria->id));
                if($executar_sub->rowCount() == 0){echo '</li>';}else{
                    echo '<ul>';
                    while($subcategoria = $executar_sub->fetchObject()){
                        echo '<li>'.$imagem_subcat.'<a href="'.PATH.'/categoria/'.$categoria->slug.'/'.$subcategoria->slug.'">'.$subcategoria->titulo.'</a></li>';                          
                    }// Termina o while da SUBCATEGORIA
                    echo '</ul></li>';
                }// Termina else dos resultados da SUBCATEGORIA
        }// Termina a while das CATEGORIAS
    }// Termina ELSE        
}// Termina a função GET MENU


public function getBanners(){
    $sqlBanners = "SELECT * FROM `loja_banners` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
    return self::conn()->query($sqlBanners);
}//pega os banners do slide principal




public function getProdutosHome($limit = false){
        if($limit == false){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `loja_produtos` ORDER BY id DESC";
        }else{
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `loja_produtos` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
        }
    return self::conn()->query($query);
}//pegar os produtos da home    


public function atualizarViewCat($slug){

    $strSQL = "UPDATE `loja_categorias` SET views = views+1 WHERE slug = ?";
    $executar_view = self::conn()->prepare($strSQL);
    $executar_view->execute(array($slug));
}//atualiza views da categoria


public function atualizarViewSub($slug){

    $strSQL = "UPDATE `loja_subcategorias` SET views = views+1 WHERE slug = ?";
    $executar_view = self::conn()->prepare($strSQL);
    $executar_view->execute(array($slug));
}//atualiza views da subcategoria


// Método de insert
public function inserir($tabela, $dados){

    $pegarCampos = array_keys($dados);
    $contarCampos = count($pegarCampos);
    $pegarValores = array_values($dados);
    $contarValores = count($pegarValores);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabela (";

    if($contarCampos == $contarValores){
        foreach($pegarCampos as $campo){
            $sql .= $campo.', ';
        }
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, ")", -2, 1);
        $sql .= "VALUES (";

        for($i = 0; $i < $contarValores; $i++){
            $sql .= "?, ";
            $i;
        }

        $sql = substr_replace($sql, ")", -2, 1);
    }else{
        return false;   
    }

    try{
        $inserir = self::conn()->prepare($sql);
        if($inserir->execute($pegarValores)){
            return true;    
        }else{
            return false;   
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        return false;
    }
}


//seleção dinamica

public function selecionar($tabela, $dados, $condicao = false, $order = false){

    $pegarValores = implode(', ', $dados);
    $contarValores = count($pegarValores);

    if($condicao == false){
        if($contarValores > 0){
            if($order != false){
                $sql = "SELECT $pegarValores FROM $tabela ORDER BY $order";
            }else{
                $sql = "SELECT $pegarValores FROM $tabela";
            }
            $this->conexao = self::conn()->prepare($sql);
            $this->conexao->execute();
            return $this->conexao;
        } 
    }else{ 

        //existe condição para selecionar

        $pegarCondCampos = array_keys($condicao);
        $contarCondCampos = count($pegarCondCampos);
        $pegarCondValores = array_values($condicao);

        $sql = "SELECT $pegarValores FROM $tabela WHERE ";
        foreach($pegarCondCampos as $campoCondicao){
            $sql .= $campoCondicao." = ? AND ";
        }
        $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -5, 5);

        foreach($pegarCondValores as $condValores){
            $dadosExec[] = $condValores;
        }
        if($order){$sql .= " ORDER BY $order";}
        $this->conexao = self::conn()->prepare($sql);
        $this->conexao->execute($dadosExec);
        return $this->conexao;
    }
}// Fim da seleção dinâmica


public function listar(){ 
    $lista = $this->conexao->fetchAll(); 
    return $lista; 
}// Fim do Listar


//metodo para envio de emails junto ao phpmailer 
public function sendMail($subject, $msg, $from, $nomefrom, $destino, $nomedestino){

    require_once "mailer/class.phpmailer.php"; 

    $mail = new PHPMailer();//instancia a classe PHPMailer
    $mail->isSMTP();//habilita envio smtp
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;//autentico o envio smtp
    // $mail->Host = 'smtp.bol.com.br'; -> PADRÃO
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    $mail->Port = '587'; // Opções: porta 25, 465 ou 587
    // Porta 465 (SSL exigido) | Porta 587 (TLS exigido) | Porta 25 (TLS NÃO exigido)

    //começar o envio do email
    $mail->Username = 'reis.demetrius@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'Mara08dema9281';
    $mail->From = $from;//email de quem envia
    @$mail->FromName = $namefrom;//nome de quem envia
    $mail->isHTML(true);//seta que é html o email
    $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($subject);
    $mail->Body = utf8_decode($msg);//corpo da mensagem
    $mail->AddAddress($destino, utf8_decode($nomedestino));//seto o destino do email

    if($mail->Send()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
} // Fim do PHP MAILER


function upload($tmp, $name, $nome, $larguraP, $pasta){

    /*$ext = end(explode('.', $name)); ---- estava assim */
    $dados = explode('.', $name);
    $ext = end($dados);
    if($ext=='jpg' || $ext == 'JPG' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'JPEG'){
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);
    }elseif($ext == 'png'){
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
    }elseif($ext == 'gif'){
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);
    }

    list($larg, $alt) = getimagesize($tmp);
    $x = $larg;
    $y = $alt;
    $largura = ($x>$larguraP) ? $larguraP : $x;
    $altura = ($largura*$y)/$x;

    if($altura>$larguraP){
            $altura = $larguraP;
            $largura = ($altura*$x)/$y;
    }
    $nova = imagecreatetruecolor($largura, $altura);
    imagecopyresampled($nova, $img, 0,0,0,0, $largura, $altura, $x, $y);

    imagejpeg($nova, $pasta.$nome);
    imagedestroy($img);
    imagedestroy($nova);
    return (file_exists($pasta.$nome)) ? true : false;
}// Fim do upload(função para cortar a imagem)
}

<h1 class="title">Cadastrar novo Produto</h1>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'cadastrar'):
include_once "inc/slug.php";
$img_padrao = $_FILES['img_padrao'];
$titulo = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'titulo'));
// Aqui segue a chamada da função
$slug = slugify($titulo);
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$subcategoria = $_POST['subcategoria'];

$val_anterior = $_POST['valAnterior'];
$val_atual = $_POST['valAtual'];
$descricao = htmlentities($_POST['descricao'], ENT_QUOTES);
$peso = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'peso'));
$qtdEstoque = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'qtdEstoque'));

$verificar_slug = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id FROM `loja_produtos` WHERE slug = ?");
$verificar_slug->execute(array($slug));
if($verificar_slug->rowCount() > 0){
    $slug .= $verificar_slug->rowCount();   
}

$val->set($titulo, 'Titulo')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($categoria, 'Categoria')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($subcategoria, 'Subcategoria')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($val_atual, 'Valor Atual')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($descricao, 'Descrição')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($peso, 'Peso')->obrigatorio();
$val->set($qtdEstoque, 'Quantidade em Estoque')->obrigatorio();

if(!$val->validar()){
    $erro = $val->getErro();
    echo '<div class="erros">Erro: '.$erro[0].'</div>';
}elseif($img_padrao['error'] == '4'){
    echo '<div class="erros">Informe uma imagem padrão para o produto!</div>';

}else{

$nomeImg = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).$img_padrao['name'];
$site->upload($img_padrao['tmp_name'], $img_padrao['name'], $nomeImg, '350', '../../produtos/');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

$campos = array('img_padrao' => $nomeImg, 
                'titulo' => $titulo, 
                'slug' => $slug, 
                'categoria' => $categoria, 
                'subcategoria' => $subcategoria, 
                'valor_anterior' => $val_anterior, 
                'valor_atual' => $val_atual, 
                'descricao' => $descricao, 
                'peso' => $peso, 
                'estoque' => $qtdEstoque, 
                'qtdVendidos' => 0, 
                'data' => $now);

    if($site->inserir('loja_produtos', $dados)){
        $_SESSION['ultimoId'] = BD::conn()->lastInsertId();
        header("Location: index.php?pagina=passo2");
    }                           
}// Fim do Validar

endif;
?>
<div id="formularios">

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="img">
        <span class="title">Imagem Padrão</span>
        <input type="file" name="img_padrao" />
    </label>

    <label>
        <span class="title">Título do Produto</span>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" class="titulo" />
    </label>

    <div class="fix">
        <label>
            <span class="title">Escolha a categoria</span>
            <select name="categoria">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione...</option>
                <?php
                    $pegar_categorias = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `loja_categorias` ORDER BY id DESC");
                    $pegar_categorias->execute();
                    while($cat = $pegar_categorias->fetchObject()){                 
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?>"><?php echo $cat->titulo; ?></option>

                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </label>

        <label>
            <span class="title">Escolha a subcategoria</span>
            <select name="subcategoria">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Selecione...</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div><!-- fix -->


    <div class="fix">
        <label>
            <span class="title">Valor Anterior</span>
            <input type="text" name="valAnterior" id="preco" class="valores" />
        </label>

        <label>
            <span class="title">Valor Atual</span>
            <input type="text" name="valAtual" id="preco1" class="valores" />
        </label>
    </div><!-- fix -->


    <label>
        <span class="title">Descreva as características do Produto</span>
        <textarea name="descricao" cols="30" rows="5" id="tiny"></textarea>
    </label>


    <div class="fix">
        <label>
            <span class="title">Peso do Produto(Ex: 0.200 = 200 gramas)</span>
            <input type="text" name="peso" class="peso-qtd" />
        </label>

        <label>
            <span class="title">Quantidade em Estoque</span>
            <input type="text" name="qtdEstoque" class="peso-qtd" />
        </label>
    </div><!-- fix -->


    <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="cadastrar" />
    <input type="submit" value="Próximo Passo" class="btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: Poderia evidenciar qual é a linha? basicamente o valor da variável é vazio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro diz que um array era esperado porem um nulo foi passado para função `array_keys()`. O inicio do problema parece estar nessa linha:

```
$campos = array('img_padrao' => $nomeImg, 
            'titulo' => $titulo, 
            'slug' => $slug, 
            //... elementos omitidos
            'data' => $now);

if($site->inserir('loja_produtos', $dados)){
```

Não existe nenhuma variável `$dados` quem tem as informações a serem inseridas é `$campos`.

Pode melhorar o tratamento de erro verificando se a entrada é um array e possui elementos do contrário cancela a excução da função.

Adicione as seguintes linhas no início da função:

```
public function inserir($tabela, $dados){
   if(!is_array($dados) || empty($dados)){
      return array('error' => true, 'msg' => 'dados em branco';
   }
```

Note que o retorno é um array em caso de falha se quiser simplificar pode retornar um false apenas.

Comment: vou verificar novamente, se errei algo...
to na dúvida... mas, obrigado por enqto...
eu retorno com a resposta!